# java8 - annotating compareTo <T> of Comparable<T> adds annotations to compareTo(Object o)

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

I have an annotation

```
package javaannotationtest;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

This is applied to compareTo in following class

```
package javaannotationtest;

public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{
    @Override
    @CustomAnnotation
    public int compareTo(Customer o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The class gives different result with java-7 and java-8 compiled code.

Java 7

```
1.7.0_45 -> public int javaannotationtest.Customer.compareTo(javaannotationtest.Customer)
 has  annotation of type javaannotationtest.CustomAnnotation
1.7.0_45 -> public int javaannotationtest.Customer.compareTo(java.lang.Object)
 has no annotation of type javaannotationtest.CustomAnnotation
```

**Note that compareTo(Object) does not have the annotation.**

Java 8

```
1.8.0 -> public int javaannotationtest.Customer.compareTo(javaannotationtest.Customer)
 has  annotation of type javaannotationtest.CustomAnnotation
1.8.0 -> public int javaannotationtest.Customer.compareTo(java.lang.Object)
 has  annotation of type javaannotationtest.CustomAnnotation
```

Java 8 has annotation added to the `compareTo(java.lang.Object)` method

Here is output from javap   for the version compiled with Java 8 (probably not relevant, it shows the annotation added to both methods)

```
  Classfile /C:/code/java8annoation/out/production/java8annoation/javaannotationtest/Customer.class
  Last modified 17 Apr, 2014; size 719 bytes
  MD5 checksum 678e0371f5f9ed5666b513c940f365a7
  Compiled from "Customer.java"
public class javaannotationtest.Customer extends java.lang.Object implements java.lang.Comparable<javaannotationtest.Customer>
  Signature: #20                          // Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Comparable<Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;>;
  SourceFile: "Customer.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #4.#23         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #24            //  javaannotationtest/Customer
   #3 = Methodref          #2.#25         //  javaannotationtest/Customer.compareTo:(Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;)I
   #4 = Class              #26            //  java/lang/Object
   #5 = Class              #27            //  java/lang/Comparable
   #6 = Utf8               <init>
   #7 = Utf8               ()V
   #8 = Utf8               Code
   #9 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #10 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #11 = Utf8               this
  #12 = Utf8               Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;
  #13 = Utf8               compareTo
  #14 = Utf8               (Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;)I
  #15 = Utf8               o
  #16 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
  #17 = Utf8               Ljavaannotationtest/CustomAnnotation;
  #18 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
  #19 = Utf8               Signature
  #20 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Comparable<Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;>;
  #21 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #22 = Utf8               Customer.java
  #23 = NameAndType        #6:#7          //  "<init>":()V
  #24 = Utf8               javaannotationtest/Customer
  #25 = NameAndType        #13:#14        //  compareTo:(Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;)I
  #26 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #27 = Utf8               java/lang/Comparable
{
  public javaannotationtest.Customer();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;

  public int compareTo(javaannotationtest.Customer);
    descriptor: (Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;)I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iconst_0      
         1: ireturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 7: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       2     0  this   Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;
            0       2     1     o   Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;
    RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
      0: #17()

  public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: aload_1       
         2: checkcast     #2                  // class javaannotationtest/Customer
         5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method compareTo:(Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;)I
         8: ireturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       9     0  this   Ljavaannotationtest/Customer;
    RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
      0: #17()
}
```

Could someone explain relevant changes in Java 8? (Will offer Bounty when is becomes eligible).

Comment: I don't understand the question. What relevant changes you're asking about? In this regard, the annotation is on both methods in both java versions.

Comment: No.  In java 7, java8.Customer.compareTo(java.lang.Object) does not have the annotation.  (Editing question to make that clear)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This change is described in the issue [JDK-6695379 - Copy method annotations and parameter annotations to synthetic bridge methods](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6695379). There doesn't seem to be much discussion about this feature but the request and justification do make sense to me.

> A DESCRIPTION OF THE REQUEST :
> When a class extends a generic classes or implements a generic interface, synthetic method may be generated to bridge between the method taking specific parameters/return and the one of the super-class/interface which is defined with Objects, because of erasure. A bridge method redirects the call to the actual method, according to Java Language Specification. However the bridge method lacks the annotations defined for the original method and its parameters.
>
> JUSTIFICATION :
> The problem arises when trying to retrieve annotations of such a method at run-time. Since it's impossible to find out reliably what classes substitute the generic parameters, we don't know what parameter to send to getMethod(...) in order to receive the correct method back. When sending Object.class (while generic parameter is a different class) getMethod will return the bridge method, which won't have the information about the original method annotations.

It is also documented in the [JDK 8 compatibility guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html):

> **Area: Tools / javac**
>
> **Synopsis**
> As of this release, parameter and method annotations are copied to synthetic bridge methods.This fix implies that now for programs like:
>
> ```
> @Target(value = {ElementType.PARAMETER})
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @interface ParamAnnotation {}
>  
> @Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD})
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @interface MethodAnnotation {}
>  
> abstract class T<A,B> {
>     B m(A a){return null;}
>  }
>  
>  class CovariantReturnType extends T<Integer, Integer> {
>      @MethodAnnotation
>      Integer m(@ParamAnnotation Integer i) {
>          return i;
>      }
>  
>     public class VisibilityChange extends CovariantReturnType {}
>  
> }
> ```
>
> Each generated bridge method will have all the annotations of the method it redirects to. Parameter annotations will also be copied. This change in the behavior may impact some annotations processor or in general any application that use the annotations.
>
> **Nature of Incompatibility**
> behavioral
>
> **RFE**
> [6695379](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6695379)

Comment: @kapep, just curious, how did you find out that this was the specific changeset?

Comment: @vrz It took some time to find it :) The changelogs didn't contain much about annotations and weren't detailed enough. The flags `ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC` in the bytecode made me curious and they seemed relevant. I think I googled something like `java 8 annotations on synthetic methods`.

Comment: @kappep, I see, thanks for your answer. I'm the author of the changeset you referred to in your answer. I was asking to know how can I ease the task of finding a given changeset to external users. Seems like adding more comments to the changeset / code may help but I'm open to suggetions / ideas.

Comment: @vrz As long as one knowns what to search for, I think it's ok. For this particular issue, I'd have liked the JDK 8 compatibility guide to be more prominent though, I never heard of it before Jaylan added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

@kapep: very nice answer. I would like to to add some complementary information about this issue. Not only annotations are copied to the bridge method. Parameter names are copied too. If you compile the example with the -parameters compiler option you get this javap output:

```
public int compareTo(Customer);
descriptor: (LCustomer;)I
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
     0: iconst_0      
     1: ireturn       
  LineNumberTable:
    line 11: 0
MethodParameters:
  Name                           Flags
  o                              
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #15()

public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
     0: aload_0       
     1: aload_1       
     2: checkcast     #2                  // class Customer
     5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method compareTo:(LCustomer;)I
     8: ireturn       
  LineNumberTable:
    line 7: 0
MethodParameters:
  Name                           Flags
  o                              synthetic  <-- see the name copied to the bridge method
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #15()
```